# Use an inverse matrix to find [x]b for the given x and B.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My linear algebra textbook has asked me to find [x]_b for the given x and basis B using an inverse matrix. The answer key does not provide anything but a solution, which doesn't help me learn the process to complete a problem like this seeing that I could have one like it on my final exam.

A similar problem with different values is worked through on Chegg; however, there are pieces missing from the explanation that leave me unable to figure out where certain numbers come from.

Could someone walk me through the process so that I can try it with other similar homework problems?

B = {[3 -5],[-4 6]}, x = [2 -6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the regular basis, suppose you have vector $\vec x=(x_0\ y_0)$. What this means is that you can get $\vec x$ by going in the $(1\ 0)$ direction $x_0$ units and then $y_0$ units in the $(0\ 1)$ direction. So you write $$\vec x=x_0(1\ 0)+y_0(0\ 1)$$
Let's suppose now that you write this vector in a similar fashion using a basis $B$, with vectors $(a\ b)$ and $(c\ d)$. Then $$\vec x=(x_0^B\ y_0^B)_B=x_0^B(a\ b)+y_0^B(c\ d)$$
Here $x_0^B$ is just a number, not $(x_0)$ to power $B$.

So how would you write this in a matrix form? Write the matrix created by putting the basis vectors vertically next to each other
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$$
Now you know the vector $\vec x$ is the same, no matter the representation. Then write all vectors as vertical matrices. You get:
$$B\begin{pmatrix}x_0^B\\y_0^B\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_0^B\\y_0^B\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{pmatrix}$$
Now multiply both sides on the left with $B^{-1}$. Using $B^{-1}B=I$ and $B^{-1}I=B^{-1}$ you get $$\begin{pmatrix}x_0^B\\y_0^B\end{pmatrix}=B^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}x_0\\y_0\end{pmatrix}$$